# Google "Account Action Required"

Tags: google-account

For the past few days, I've been getting this notice on top of all Google sites (Search engine, Gmail, Calendar, Contacts, etc.):
[image: Account Action Required]

If I click on it, it takes me to [this page](https://consent.google.com/privacyreminder/signedin), which actually doesn't allow or ask me to do anything.

This notice keeps coming back. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I'd expect there to be some sort of confirmation that you've read the page. (I don't see it because I've been through the privacy checkup.)

Answer (score 3):

Once you go to that page (link you included), scroll to bottom and click the blue GO TO MY ACCOUNT link.

Usually just *going* to the page will cease the notifications.  If it comes back soon, you'll need to actually go to that page and do the Security and Privacy checkups.